# How to compare 2 files and extract information

Tags: shell, unix

i have two files , one is var.txt and another res.dat file

var.txt contains informaton like below

```
date,request,sales,item
20171015,1,123456,216    
20171015,1,123456,217
20171015,2,345678,214    
20171015,3,456789,218
```

and res.dat contains is a one huge file contains information like below

```
RTCCVB01 213456 123456 216
.
.
.
VBPCVB01

RTCCVB01 213456 345678 214
.
.
.
VBPCVB01

RTCCVB01 213456 123456 217
.
.
.
VBPCVB01

RTCCVB01 213456 456789 218
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

For a unique request i have to create a separate dat file, 
for example
in var.txt 
for second column request 
for Request 1 there is sales 123456 which has 2 item 216 and 217 so the dat file will be created like below

for Request 1 - 123456.dat

```
RTCCVB01 213456 123456 216
.
.
VBPCVB01

RTCCVB01 213456 123456 217
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

for Request 2 345678.dat

```
RTCCVB01 213456 345678 214
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

for Request 3 456789.dat

```
RTCCVB01 213456 456789 218
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

sales occur at 50-56 position in res.dat file
item occur at 72-79 position in res.dat file

i have to write a shell script which will do below for each unique request from var.txt it will take sales and item and extract information from res.dat and will be creating separate dat files till all request number is done .

if i do  cut -d, -f3,4 var.txt
                                                     output will be               123456 216

123456 217

345678 216

456789 218

i have to use above output and recursively search in res.dat file and accordingly based on request will be creating dat files

Comment: Good christ man. Sort your examples out.

Comment: is very simple. i will provide answer after i finish my cuppa tea

Comment: wait wait wait, u r on linux?

Comment: @Rico its in unix

Comment: ok, let me think of some high tech solution for this. the simple solution i think right now is read var.txt into array, then for each element in array split it by last index of "," so that will give u item number, then look for that item number in res.dat but this would need you to read the res.dat many times

Comment: @Rico yes with the item number , i need also to check the sales because sales is unique number here but item number can be duplicate.thank you for your help

Comment: @user229374, format your input data to make it readable

Answer (score 1):

Like this? The `var.dat` seems futile based on the expected output.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="VBPCVB01\n"}{f=$3 ".dat"; print >> f; close(f)}' res.dat
$ cat 123456.dat
RTCCVB01 213456 123456 216
.
.
.
VBPCVB01

RTCCVB01 213456 123456 217
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

Explained:

```
awk '
BEGIN { RS=ORS="VBPCVB01\n" }  # set the delimiters appropriately
{
    f=$3 ".dat"                # set $3 as the filename
    print >> f                 # append records to the file
    close(f)                   # close the file (due to "huge file") 
}                              # to avoid running out of fds (unknown unix)
' res.dat                      # this file only
```

Comment: if you see the var.txt the second column contain request, third column contains sales and the fourth column is the item,i have to take inputs from var.txt which will be the sales which is unique and its corresponding item , for example for request 1 , there is unique sales -123456 and it has 2 items no 216 and 217 , so it will be creating a single dat file and so on for each request it will be creating a single dat file

Answer (score 1):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '/RTCCVB01/{fn=$3}{print > fn".dat"}' res.dat
```

---

This command contains 2 sets of curly braces: The control goes to the first set of braces only on encountering a line containing the pattern `RTCCVB01`. The second set will be encountered by every line since there is no condition and hence always true.

On encountering the pattern `RTCCVB01`, a new file name is created and stored. When the first `RTCCVB01` comes, `fn` will contain `123456` and the control goes to the next set of braces and the record is written to `123456.dat`, and the subsequent records go the file `123456.dat` till the next `RTCCVB01` comes.

---

```
cat 123456.dat
RTCCVB01 213456 123456 216
.
.
.
VBPCVB01

RTCCVB01 213456 123456 217
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

---

```
cat 345678.dat
RTCCVB01 213456 345678 214
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

---

```
cat 456789.dat
RTCCVB01 213456 456789 218
.
.
.
VBPCVB01
```

Comment: Nice compact solution. The resulting files (except the last) have a trailing empty line. Based on the careless formatting of the original question, that should be ok.

Comment: @ULick, yes, trailing empty line may be reasonable in case of further appending `>>` new records to  a file

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest , if you see the var.txt the second column contain request, third column contains sales and the fourth column is the item,i have to take inputs from var.txt which will be the sales which is unique and its corresponding item , for example for request 1 , there is unique sales -123456 and it has 2 items no 216 and 217 , so it will be creating a single dat file

Comment: @user229374 So it seems. However, there is no requirement for it and based on the expected output it is not needed. If there is a requirement, please update it the OP.

Comment: @user229374, It looks very much that `res.data` contains all request data with sales. I mean your `res.data` reflects your `var.txt` pretty explicitly

Comment: @JamesBrown  i have updated , can you please check now

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes , i have to take input from var.txt and extract information from res.dat and create a dat file

Comment: @JamesBrown  i was trying below                                                                      for id in `cut -d,-f3 var.txt`;do                                                                             sed -n "/RTCCVB01.*$ID/,/VBPCVB01/p" res.dat > $ID.dat                               done                                                                                                                      but i have to search correspondingly item also which i am facing difficulty

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest i was trying below for id in cut -d,-f3 var.txt;do sed -n "/RTCCVB01.*$ID/,/VBPCVB01/p" res.dat > $ID.dat done but i have to search correspondingly item also which i am facing difficulty